# CSS displayed differently when viewed on a SmartPhone or tablet

Tags: html, css

So i am working on a website and there is a little problem. When the website is viewed from a computer everything is fine, but when viewed on a smartphone or tablet the 3 bar menu button disappears? Here's the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });

    </script>

  </head>
  <body id="all">
      <div id="headerMenu">
          <div id="logo">
              <a href="/">Website</a>
          </div>
      </div>

    <div id="page-content">
        <a href="/">Link</a>
        <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
          <ul>
              <form action="/search/index.php" method="POST">
                  <li><input id="search" name="search" size=15 type="text" placeholder="search..."></li>
              </form>
              <li><hr></li>
              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
              <li><hr></li>
              <li><a href="/register">Login / Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
          <div class="swipe-area"></div>
          <a data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

```css
  body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18;
}

#headerMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #212021;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

#logo a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #212021;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 14px;
    left: 10px;
}


#page-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%;
}

#headerMenu img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #212021;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 7px;
    left: 70%;
}

#menu img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #212021;
    position: fixed;
    top: -2px;
    left: 85%;
}

#search {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #424242;
    border: 1px solid #212021;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  -webkit-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.container.open-sidebar {
  right: 240px;
}

#sidebar {
  background: #313031;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  right: -240px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #313031;
  -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar ul li:hover a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #212021;
  border: 1px solid #313031;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
}

.main-content .content{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content #sidebar-toggle {
  background: #212021;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 7px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 13px;
  right: 2%;
}

.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;   
}

.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
   margin-bottom: 0;   
}






/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 0px) and (max-width : 500px) {

    #page-content {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width : 250px) and (max-width : 300px) {

    #logo a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Oxygen", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 23px;
        background-color: #212021;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 10px;
    }

    #headerMenu img {
        width: 37px;
        height: 37px;
        background-color: #212021;
        position: fixed;
        top: 7px;
        left: 65%;
    }

    #page-content {
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }

    #sidebar {
      background: #313031;
      margin-top: 80px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 170px;
      height: 100%;
      right: -240px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width : 0px) and (max-width : 250px) {

    #logo a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Oxygen", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 19px;
        background-color: #212021;
        position: fixed;
        top: 17px;
        left: 5px;
    }

    #headerMenu img {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        background-color: #212021;
        position: absolute;
        top: 7px;
        left: 60%;
    }

    #page-content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .container.open-sidebar {
      right: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar {
      background: #313031;
      margin-top: 80px;
      position: absolute;
      right: -250px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

}





@media only screen and (min-height : 300px) and (max-height : 400px) {

    #sidebar ul li a {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      padding-left: 25px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-height : 0px) and (max-height : 340px) {

    #sidebar ul li a {
      padding-top: 7px;
      padding-bottom: 7px;
      padding-left: 25px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you include the contents of style.css as well?

Comment: Did you include the <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

Comment: I included these at the top`<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: ah now i see it. put it by itself, just to verify its actually working, or check in chrome to see if its registering

Comment: I commented them out and viewed it on my phone and it still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix,
In your 0 to 250 max media query, you have this.

## sidebar {

```
  background: #313031;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -250px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The right -250px is pushing your menu off the page. Put together a jsfiddle or codepen to test and see if I am correct.

Comment: Also your page media queries are really strange. It should go 480 max then 980 then 1280 and up. You have media queries that are showing at 0 to 250 and 250 to 300 and etc etc... its not normal.

Comment: how do i make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.net and add all your code, then copy the link and paste it.

Comment: It wont let me add the external resource?

Comment: I used screenfly to test it and it works with all sizes? http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//192.168.1.7&w=320&h=533&a=36&s=1

Comment: Ok, Ive just noticed that it only disappears in google chrome not in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromecompatfaq

> Use of Browser-Specific CSS or JavaScript objects The Symptom:
>
> Some CSS styling does not work in Google Chrome, even though they seem
>   fine in IE or Firefox. The problem:
>
> Each browser has its own private CSS selectors and JavaScript objects.
>   Use of these types of markup is, by definition, not compatible with
>   other browsers. These should only be used for non-critical tasks (e.g.
>   adding text shadows). It is safest not to use them at all.
>   Recommendations:
>
> ```
> Do not use document.all in JavaScript. This is an outdated IE feature, all modern browsers support document.getElementById() and you
> ```
>
> should use that instead.
>       When diagnosing JavaScript issues, use Google Chrome's built-in JavaScript debugger.
>       Do not use browser-specific (e.g. -moz-*, -webkit-*, -ie-*) css selectors such as -moz-center or -webkit-highlight for critical visual
>   features of your site, instead use standard CSS.
>       Do not use CSS expressions (e.g. width:expression()). These only work in IE, have serious performance issues and have been deprecated.
>
> Useful Tools
>
> We've found the following tools extremely useful when diagnosing
>   compatibility problems with Websites. Using them can greatly decrease
>   the amount of effort and guesswork that goes into fixing compatibility
>   issues:
>
> ```
> Google Chrome has a variety of built-in tools to help developers track down compatibility and performance issues.
> Firebug - An excellent Firefox extension that can help examining markup, JavaScript and performance issues.
> Fiddler - A free Windows-only tool that allows you to examine and replay HTTP requests and responses.
> ```
>
> Additional Resources
>
> ```
> Google Chrome Webmaster FAQ - Contains all the information in this document and loads more.
> quirksmode - Useful Information about which features are implemented in which browser.
> Reporting a bug in Google Chrome - guidelines and pointers on how to write an effective clear bug report.
> ```